# Grub menu from a previous dual-boot showing instead of new Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I bought an Asus T100 Chi from a friend. He had previously installed Android alongside Windows. I wiped the drive (except for the EFI partition) and installed Ubuntu by following this guide:.

drive.google.com/file/d/0B4s5KNXf2Z36eERKSU9ka3NNY1k/view

However now I can't get the Grub menu to let me boot into Ubuntu. I know Ubuntu installed properly to the tablet because I can boot into it by loading a live USB, entering its Grub command line (following step 4 of [this guide](http://www.jfwhome.com/2016/01/04/latest-steps-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-asus-t100ta/)) and booting this way.

I installed `grub-efi-ia32` and ran `sudo update-grub`. I also tried running the Ubuntu Boot-Repair tool. When booting, I can still see Grub menu set up from the time my friend had installed Android. How can I get the correct Grub menu to appear?

I've checked the BIOS and can't see any more drives/options available to boot from.

[image]

Comment: It's `sudo update-grub`, just in case it isn't a typo. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yes that was a typo. I corrected the original post. Thanks.